# How to calculate XOR

Tags: python

can you write it step by step. details in below.change string to a  list of Asccii code then pruduct all the element of list then calculate EXOR.

```
from functools import reduce    
my_string="Ahmad Ali"    
ascii_list=[ord(c) for c in my_string]    
number=reduce(lambda x,y: x*y, ascii_list,2)    
print(number)
```

Comment: Is there anyone to help me

Comment: Firstly, the backslashes in your code are syntax errors. Secondly, the 2 you are using as the last argument of reduce() acts as an initial element. You are calculating the product of the elements in ascii_list and then multiplying that by 2. Thirdly, it's not at all clear what you want the XOR of. Please clarify.